# How to Set iframe height dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe which loads a src say urlA. This urlA interanally makes another ajax call for some url say urlB.

```
<iframe src="urlA" id="iframe1"/>
```

I have a load function attached to above iframe as:

```
$("#iframe1").load(function() {
    setIframeHeight(); // another function calls which sets iframe height according to its content
});
```

My problem is this that the ablve load function gets calls when urlA returns, but the actual content which is required after all the operation is of urlB. So, how do i wait for urlB to complete and set iframe height accordingly?

Or is there any event which gets fired on any change in iframe content so that i can use that to update my iframe's height?

Thanks.

Comment: Is urlA your domain? Otherwise the answer will that you can't wait.

Comment: show the code for changing the src...

Comment: using iframe makes google listing hard for you

Answer (score -1):

using jquery :

```
   $('#iframe1').css('height',auto);
```

Comment: `auto` doesn't help for `iframe`s

Answer (score -1):

When Iframe content is loaded - get its height and set its style accordingly:

```
$("iframe").load(function() {
    this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + "px";
});
```